# When should I use annotations vs. model methods in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a situation where I need to add additional data to the objects within a Queryset, and I have troubles understanding when it is really beneficial to perform queries that have annotations, over just implementing custom methods on the model class.

As a generic example:

This:

```
 MyModel.objects
        .filter(
            some_field=some_value
        )
        .annotate(
            has_something=Exists(
                Something.objects.filter(
                    whatever=OuterRef('pk'),
                    start_date__gte=SIX_MONTHS_AGO
                )
            ),
            something_else= ... # Some complex query
        )
```

Versus this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    some_field = CharField()

    def has_something(self):
        return (self.something_set
                    .filter(start_date__gte=SIX_MONTHS_AGO)
                    .count() > 0)

    def something_else(self):
        ... # Make some other queries


class Something(models.Model):
    whatever = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)
    start_date = models.DateField()
```

So in both cases I can do something like this wherever I need to (for example, in the templates):

```
{% for obj in my_model_queryset %}
    {{ obj.has_something }}
{% endfor %}
```

As far as I know, when doing annotations all the work is done by the database engine and everything can be done in a single database hit (I think?). On the other hand, when implementing a method on the model class, additional queries might be performed if you need to get reverse lookups, or data from a foreign model.

I just want to ask, is there any rule of thumb, or any guidance that you all consider for when to use one approach over the another? Especially if the annotations get really complex (e.g, using Q objects, Subqueries, GroupConcat, and so on)

Thanks.

Comment: Use a profiler such as Django Debug Toolbar, Django Silk (or my own https://github.com/valohai/django-cavalry) to figure out when a view/endpoint is making too many queries and optimize when you need to using annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here an exemple :

```py
model_datas = Model.objects.filter(
    field_date__date__range=[date_from, date_to]
).order_by(
    'field_date'
)


# each line will perform a query here :(
for model in model_datas:
    writer.writerow([
        model.user.id,
        model.user.email,
        model.business_provider.encode('utf-8'),
        model.field_date.date()
    ])
```

This will perform 1 query for all `Model` + 1 query with a join on `User` for each `model` in loop

But you can do it in only one query :

```py
csv_datas = Model.objects.filter(
    field_date__date__range=[date_from, date_to]
).order_by(
    'field_date'
).annotate(
    user_id=F('model__user_id'),
    user_email=F('model__user__email'),
    business_provider=F('model__provider_name'),
    field_date=F('model__field_date'),
).values(
    'user_id',
    'user_email',
    'business_provider',
    'field_date'
)

for data in csv_datas:
    writer.writerow([
        data["user_id"],
        data["user_email"],
        data["business_provider"].encode('utf-8'),
        data["field_date"].date()
    ])
```

Here only one query is perform, that is the thing to do.

In Django never do a loop with subquery performed, it's really bad for performance.

with `F` and `Q` you can do pretty complex stuff, what i like to do when it's really complex, is to split in multiple query and just use :

```py
query_1_ids = Model.objects.filter(XXXX).values_list('pk', flat=True)

query2 = Model2.objects.filter(model__pk__in=query_1_ids)
```

That my rule of thumb, but if this didn't fit, i do a python process for aggregating in a `set` or `dict` what i need (but it's really rare to be here)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! Yes, I (almost) never loop over a queryset. That's why the two approaches I'm considering is annotating vs. implement a @property or a method in the model class.

Comment: Dont forget that Django queryset is lazy, so when you iterate in a loop on a template, you will make an extra query for each element in loop, {{ obj.has_something }} will perform in your exemple an extra query for each elements :)

Comment: Well noted! Thanks. So basically the *best* way to go is to throw all the load to the DB engine, regardless of how complex the annotatinos and queries can get?

Comment: what is costly is database hit (mecanical i/o), it's better to have complex (but readable) annotations :) database are born to complex computation, it will in 99% of database better to make 1 huge query than thousand of small queries. Personal exemple, we had in my work thousand of profile in our CRM, looping and queries for each profile loaded in 11s, 1 big fattas query performed the job in less than 1s :)